# Automatically renaming files during a TFS Merge

Tags: version-control, tfs, build-automation, versioning, branching-and-merging

My development team is in the process of implementing branching and merging in TFS. Our software is contained in one solution, which many projects embedded within. One of those projects contains all the SQL scripts to keep our databases versioned.

We are having trouble figuring out how to handle the Database project during merging. For example, whenever a developer needs to make any changes to the database (add/remove a stored proc, create table, add indexes, etc) we create a script file. Each file gets named with a version number. For instance, if the last script file that was checked in is named 4.1.0.1, I would name my new script 4.1.0.2. We use these file names to match a software version with the corresponding database version it needs to run.

Say I create a branch off our main code branch to do a new feature. I do all the coding, and I put all my SQL changes in one script file and add it to the DB project. Obviously I could just merge from the main code branch into my new branch to make sure I have the latest list of SQL scripts so I could name it correctly. The problem is new script files are added several times throughout the day and we think we're going to have a ton of merge conflicts with the script naming.

I'd like to somehow automate this, so a developer can just add a script with some random name and during the merge there is a hook or event that will figure out which files are new to the main code base and also how to correctly name those files so the developers don't have to worry about it. For example, I can just create a new file called "new_script.sql", and when I merge that back to the main code branch it will get renamed to 4.1.0.2

Previously I've used tools such as RoundHouse to take care of all the SQL versioning, however at my current job we use Sybase SQL Anywhere 10, and I haven't been able to track down something similar to RoundHouse that will work with Sybase.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to automate a task during a TFS merge? I'm assuming this can be done using PowerShell, but my concern is that most of the development team is unfamiliar with PowerShell and I was hoping to be able to automate this task without the developer needing to leave the team explorer window.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are absolute right that you will get naming conflicts if you continue to use this strategy and introduce branches.

I think you have two options:

1. When adding these files on a branch, add them prefixed with the branch name. Eg. branch_0.1.sql and branch_0.2.sql.  Then when you merge your branch back into the trunk, you would have to rename these to the correct name.  You could write a program to do this for you, and would be fairly simple.
   To make this simpler, you could only create one SQL file per branch too and just keep adding to that one SQL file.  Then even you merge it's a very simply process.
2. Ditch the self versioned files.  Tfs is version control. There isn't much need to version the files yourself. We use Visual Studio database projects for our database versioning and this works absolute fine.  I guess you would need to change something in your deployment strategy if you changed this.

I hope this helps.